# Error while setting the workflow from the miodin package in R

Tags: r

I am getting an error saying

> Error in object@promisedInterfaces[[spec$oModule]] <- spec : 
>     invalid subscript type 'S4'"

when I use the function "MiodinWorkflow" from miodin package.

I have used the following code:

```
 mw <- MiodinWorkflow(name = "Lecture 4")
  mw <- mw +
    downloadRepositoryData(
      name = "RNA downloader",
      accession = "E-MTAB-7473",
      repository = "ArrayExpress",
      path = "data",
      type = "processed")+
    importProcessedData(
      name = "RNA-seq importer",
      experiment = "sequencing",
      dataType = "rna",
      studyName = "E-MTAB-7473",
      assayName = "RNA-seq",
      datasetName = "E-MTAB-7473",
      contrastName = "Treatment") %>%
    processSequencingData(
      name = "RNA-seq processor",
      contrastName = "Treatment",
      filterLowCount = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try replacing `+` with `%>%`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked